# Is it possible to rename an SQL Server 2005 instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I would like to change the name of my SQL Server instance.  Is there a simple way of doing this or is a significant effort required?  Note, this is a named instance - not the default instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen a few makeshift ways of doing this, but I don't have confidence in any of them.  I think I will simply install a new instance and transfer my information over.

Answer (score 1):

The only way is a reinstall. See this similar thread for more info: [SQL Server, convert a named instance to default instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35026/sql-server-convert-a-named-instance-to-default-instance#35641)

Answer (score 1):

Or you could try this method:
http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.sqlserver.server/browse_thread/thread/544c4eaf43ddfaf3/f1bdcd1ec9cab158#f1bdcd1ec9cab158

Answer (score 0):

Renaming does't work well on the registry. Install a new isntance.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no simple way of renaming a SQL Server instance, one can [create SQL aliases](https://web.archive.org/web/20190916200831/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/twickers/archive/2009/12/08/136830.aspx).