# WCF NamedPipe IPC communication

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, ipc, named-pipes

I want to communicate with two application using WCF NamedPipe IPC, The connection is not being established between server and client because some information or the address used in app.config is incorrect.

I suppose something is missing because of which the communication is not established, Please help ?

ex : 
Server Side

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="IService1">
           <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/Service1"
                  binding="netNamedPipeBinding"
                  contract="NamedPipeService.IService1"
                  name="ConsoleServiceEndpoint" />
        </service>
     </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Client Side :

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/Service1"
            binding="netNamedPipeBinding" contract="NamedPipeService.IService1"            name="ConsoleServiceEndpoint" />
   </client>
```

Comment: Will you please complete the question?

Comment: Is the client and server on the same box?  You do know NamedPipe is same box only?

Comment: Hi Client and Server are on the same computer but not included in the same Solution.

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is associated with SQL Server, another question was just posed similar and you may be in the same position.

[Please check this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14815297/microsoft-sql-server-native-client-10-0-login-timeout-expired)  It may be associated with if the protocols for the sql server having the Named Pipes enabled or not.