# I am trying to connect to SQL Server through command prompt getting an error:

Tags: sql-server

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : SQL Server Network Interfaces: Connection string is not valid [87]. .
>
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
>
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

I have checked all the services related to SQL Server are up and running also check the connection using command:

```
sqlcmd -S PSARGAR-T420\MSSQLSERVER -d master -U MDMUser_901  -P Psargar@123
```

I am using SQL Server authentication still I am facing same error.

Comment: I am able to connect from Studio but from cmd i unable to connect sql server

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sqlcmd -S PSARGAR-T420 -d master -U MDMUser_901  -P Psargar@123
```

Obtained from here: 
[SQL Server Network Interfaces: Connection string is not valid [87]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28659796/sql-server-network-interfaces-connection-string-is-not-valid-87)

Comment: Thanks I tried this.  But it shows the error like : Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [3].