# Rename SQL Server Express to (.)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I installed SQL Server Express on my machine and I can only connect to in in SSMS using `.\SqlExpress`. How do I change it so it becomes `.`?

I want to do this for SQLExpress which is different that the answers that are found here "[SQL Server, convert a named instance to default instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35026/sql-server-convert-a-named-instance-to-default-instance)"

Comment: The questions asked in the previous question applies only to SQL Server Full