# SQL Server 2012 Server Name duplicated

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I just setup SQL Server 2012 on a test server, and I can't figure out why my Server name is being duplicated.  Should be 'DEVSVR' not 'DEVSVR\DEVSVR'

[image]

I've tried renaming my server name w/ sp_dropserver and sp_addserver which looks to have worked when I run a query on sys.servers but @@SERVERNAME still shows up as 'DEVSVR\DEVSVR'

[image]

Since this is my first time having to install SQL Server, I'm thinking I might have missed something during installation.  Any insight on how I can rename this server without having to resort to uninstalling and re-installing SQL Server would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I didn't have it set as my default instance.  I did the following...

- Open SQL Server Configuration Manager
- Click SQL Server Network Configuration
- Click Protocols for INSTANCENAME you want to make available (i.e. SQLExpress)
- Right-click TCP/IP and click Enabled
- Right-click TCP/IP and go to Properties
- Set TCP Port to 1433 in the IPAll Section. and Clear TCP Dynamic Ports
- Go to SQL Server Services
- Right-click your SQL Server (INSTANCENAME) and click Restart

Reference: [SQL Server, convert a named instance to default instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35026/sql-server-convert-a-named-instance-to-default-instance)