# After changing the TCP ports of named SQL Server instance while logging through SSMS to localhost or . I still login to the old default SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, tcp, ssms

I have installed named instance of the SQL Server, later I wanted to use it as default instance. So I did this:

- Open `SQL Server Configuration Manager`
- Click `SQL Server Network Configuration`
- Click `Protocols for INSTANCENAME` you want to make available (i.e. SQLExpress)
- Right-click `TCP/IP` and click `Enabled`
- Right-click `TCP/IP` and go to `Properties`

  - Go to the `IP Addresses` tab
  - Scroll down to the `IPAll` section
  - Clear the field `TCP Dynamic Ports` (i.e. *empty/blank*)
  - Set `TCP Port` to `1433`
  - Click `Ok`
- Go to `SQL Server Services`
- Right-click your `SQL Server (INSTANCENAME)` and click `Restart`

[image: SQL Server Configuration Manager]

This made my the named instance listen on the default port. Then I did the same for the default server and I changed TCP port to the 1434 so they don't interfere. 
I restarted the computer but still when I login through SQL Server Management Studio and give localhost as the server name I still access the old default server.

Why is it so, how to fix it?

Comment: Are you supplying the name of the instance in your connection string? I.e. `localhost\SQLEXPRESS`? If not, regardless of what port it's running on, simply passing `localhost` will connect to an instance with the Default instance name (`MSSQLSERVER`).

Comment: @Larnu I thought that this what I did will cause it to be default instance. Can I rename the instances?

Comment: No. The Instance name cannot be changed.

Comment: @Larnu So what's the point in doing this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11921896/1123020 if this doesn't change a thing?

Comment: The difference there is that there is no instance with the default instance name.

Comment: @Larnu So if I remove the default instance, then it should work?

Comment: People are entitled to lunch breaks you know ;). And most likely. I can't definitively say yes, as I haven't tested.

Answer (score 1):

> > when I login through SQL Server Management Studio and give localhost as the server name I still access the old default server

Probably because you are connecting over Shared Memory, not TCP/IP.

EG connect and run

```
select net_transport
from sys.dm_exec_connections
where session_id = @@spid
```

If you specify tcp:localhost you should connect to the target instance.

Note in this configuration you'll want to disable the other network protocols to avoid this confusion.